# How to get href value of anchor tag if it has image tag in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i tried to get the image src with jquery here is the code below

```
jQuery("img").click(function() {
    var im = $(this).attr('src'); 
    alert(im);
    return false;
});
```

above working fine i can get the image src. likewise i try to get href value of anchor tag only if it has a image tag in it otherwise it shouldn't.Below is a example containing image tag in it.

```
<a href="some.something"><img src="image1.jpg"></a>
```

how to do this?what selector is better?any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('img').parent('a') // Will select anchors who are `img` elements parents. 

$('img').parent('a').each(function(_,el){console.log(el.href)}); // will take the href attr.
```

To use with click function:

```
$('img').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();//I use this to not direct myself to linked page for testing
var parent = $(e.target).parent('a');
console.log(parent.attr('href'));
})
```

Comment: can this be accessed on click event? @raam86

Comment: i tried like this `jQuery('img').parent('a').click(function(){});`

Comment: Thanks bro.why concole.log? if u have time explain:)

Comment: I find this function better for debugging since it sometimes give more information and it is far less annoying

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/76pZf/)**

It's always easier if you have an id on the image.

- To check if image `src` **has** parent that is a `<a>` you can use: `if ($(this).parent('a').length) {`

Inside the function triggered by click on image:

- To get `href` value from parent that is a `<a>` tag you can use: `$(this).parent('a').prop('href');`
- To get `src` value from the image use `$(this).prop('src');`

**The whole code:**

```
$('img').click(function () {
    $(this).preventDefault;
if ($(this).parent('a').length) {
    var im = $(this).prop('src');
    var aHref = $(this).parent('a').prop('href');
    alert('First alert with imc src: '+im);
    alert('Second alert with link href: '+aHref);
}
});
```

Comment: @raj, thanks! Just updated answer also with href. You can check here also: http://jsfiddle.net/76pZf/